# Mapping an UIView on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, dictionary

I currently scratch my head for a few days about "How to cartography an UIView on iOS".

Explanations:

I have some data with a lot of locations (longitude and latitude). I'm searching how can I, from a country, display these locations. I can't use a MapView because it's only for one country. On this map, I would like display the locations. It's like Google Analytic do, but in web application: [image]

So, my question is: is it possible to "transform" an UIView into a map ? Do you have any idea how can I start this project ?

**EDIT:**

Maybe I have to use the [MapBox SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/) ?

**EDIT 2:**

Here one method which convert coordinate to a screen location (MapBox). It can be useful!
[coordinateToPixel](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MapBox/1.1.0/Classes/RMMapView.html#//api/name/coordinateToPixel:)

Thank you so much for your suggestions and ideas ;)

Best regards,
Lapinou.

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. Are you saying you want to display map data inside a view? You want to build your own map display control and feed it map data? That is probably more than a 1-person project, and certainly more than we could describe in a forum post. And by the way there is nothing restricting an MKMapView to only show a single country at a time. As I write this I am looking at a map view that is displaying a map of all of western Europe, and all the constituent countries are shown. As I zoom in I see more detail on each country, and as I zoom out, I see more countries.

Comment: This should be done using UIMapKit and if you want it to display just the one country, you use boundaries and a zoom level restriction. You are going about this all the wrong way my friend.

Comment: Yes, that is. I know it's really complex. But maybe I can achieve this by using the MapBox SDK...

Comment: I presume you're talking about a map that can zoom, not just a single image of the UK?

Comment: @MartinH No, it's like an image. No interaction enabled, juste display some statistic on map based on my location data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its just a static image and there is no zooming then thats maybe not *that* complex, unless there's some complexity I'm overlooking.

Using the scale of the map image you can convert that to points i.e. 1 point vertically is 10 miles. 
Then if you have your plot point co-ordinates you should be able to convert those to UIView x.y co-ordinate.

You could pick a reference point in the UK whose lat/long you know as an anchor from which to calculate the lat and long offsets from for the points you want plot.

Lets say there is a hypothetical tiny island in the top left hand of your picture, you can find out the lat/long for it and plot it at x,y of 0,0 when displaying your map image.
Then you can calculate the difference in lat/long from that reference point of your pins and convert that difference into an x,y offset from 0,0.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm searching for now! Thank you :D